# tproxy per user

Tags: proxy, ipv6, http-proxy, squid

I'm in the process of adding some parental control to my box (http filtering).

The box is used by the whole family (one account for each member) and squid runs on the very same machine.

I have two squid instances, one (for adults) only for caching, one (for children) using squidGuard.

To choose between both squid instances, I use `--uid-owner` with NAT rules.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner $owner -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports $port
```

(ditto for ip6tables)

Currently I use NAT for both IPv4 and IPv6 (with a fairly recent linux kernel), but Squid says that "intercept" only supports IPv4. I would like to have IPv6 too.

I tried to use TPROXY (e.g. using [these](http://www.pmoghadam.com/homepage/HTML/slackware-12.2-squid-3.1.5.1-tproxy-linux-router.html) rules) but I failed because I need `--uid-owner` which iptables wants to set on POSTROUTING (not on PREROUTING).

Those rules are:

```
iptables -t mangle -N DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A DIVERT -j ACCEPT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m socket -j DIVERT
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1 --on-port 3129
```

How do I add appropriate `--uid-owner` rules in that mangle table? **I mean, how do I decide to forward to port 3128 or 3129?**

**Edit:** please don't answer saying that my NAT rule works well. I know that. I need to get rid of NAT because Squid's NAT is IPv4 only. So please, again, no NAT. Only TPROXY or mangle or whatever you call it that works with the `mangle` rules above.

Comment: Is your "box" a router or the system you are working on? You don't make that clear and the point is: `--uid-owner` makes sense on a user system only, `PREROUTING` on a router only. The page you refer to is about router configuration.

Comment: ok sorry. Both. I'm at home, I don't have that many computers ;-) I'll clarify, thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `--uid-owner` in `PREROUTING`, you need it in `OUTPUT` (like in your example).

Comment: so I just need to replace -t nat by -t mangle and all is well?

Comment: @cadrian No, `REDIRECT` works in `nat` only but `nat` has an `OUTPUT` chain, too. Your example rule should be enough. `PREROUTING` is not used for locally generated packets and `POSTROUTING` can't do `DNAT` / `REDIRECT`.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. How do I use tproxy then?

Comment: @cadrian I don't understand the problem. I don't know tproxy but it probably is a proxy server listening in the localhost interface. Thus your rule should work. I assume it doesn't; otherwise you wouldn't have asked... Please provide the output of `tcpdump -i lo -n`. Are there `INPUT` rules blocking traffic to `lo`?

Comment: I tried to clarify the question. Please read it again. Do you now understand my problem? Thanks.

Comment: And why do you talk about `lo`? (I guess you are talking about the loopback device, but why…)