# tproxy for only one application?

Tags: iptables, proxy

I need to route all udp traffic from one application through a proxy, and I think [tproxy](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/tproxy.html) is a good option for this. I can run the app with a special user and filter by `uid`/`gid` before `set-mark` in `DIVERT`, but those marked packets got mixed up with other forwarded packets in `PREROUTING`. Is there a way to separate them or any other way to achieve this?

This question is similar to [tproxy per user](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76469/tproxy-per-user) but that one's unanswered.

Comment: `tproxy` oh I very vaguely remember that! But, seriously, why not simply run your application in a network namespace? This seems pretty much like one of the core use cases of network namespaces!

Comment: can you explain your real traffic ? is it incoming traffic you want to proxy or outgoing traffic or both ?

Comment: is it a traffic from your local machine or from another machine on your LAN ?

Comment: @dominix The app is a p2p game. It does NAT discovery using TURN and communicate with other peers on the internet with UDP. I basically want to tunnel all this traffic through a server with better connectivity because my ISP is bad. So after the initial hole punching on the proxy server it becomes 2way.

Comment: @MarcusMüller This could very well work! I'm thinking of running the game(see above) and `tproxy` in a namespace. `PREROUTING` on `mangle` only handles incoming traffic, so everything with dst!=<veth ip or loopback or broadcast> will be the marked packets. On a second thought, this still applies on the host machine, but since it's ip isn't fixed(dhcp), this is more difficult. A tun device in the namespace can also work, but we'll need to add a route dynamically for the proxy server to go through. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: so if I understand correctly it is both incoming and outgoing traffic with a external proxy. So do you have control over the proxy ? is it yours or someone else proxy ?

Comment: @dominix I'm writing the proxy program as I didn't find any existing solution. On windows  I've used some "ping boosters" that are basically a tun/tap device with a predefined whitelist to the game servers, but as this one uses p2p I don't have a ip list.